# Can I adjust the sensitivity of 3D Touch?

Tags: ios, iphone, multi-touch

I find that I have to touch more firmly than I would like to activate 3D Touch. Is there a way to make 3D Touch react to a firmer or softer touch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the sensitivity to light, medium, or firm by going to **Settings > General > Accessibility > 3D Touch**.

[image: settings]

Comment: I'm looking forward to trying this out... when Apple eventually get around to delivering my pre-ordered 6s... grrr...